# Error due to Changing minSdkVersion from 21 to 14

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, sdk

Original =  minSdkVersion 21

But when I changed

> minSdkVersion 21

to

> minSdkVersion 14

I am getting an error:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Error is already descriptive . You can use Media projection below API21. Check for build version before using this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your are using [MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html#createScreenCaptureIntent()) which is only available from API 21.

Please read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html

Comment: So, I have to change minSdk back to 21 or there any other command which is available from API 14 instead of MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()

Comment: Sadly, there is no alternative for it afaik.